# Apache airflow FileSensor return a file name

Tags: file, airflow, task, sensors

I'd like to know a way to get the file name detected by the file sensor when the *filepath* parameter is set to **.xlsx*.

I need to retrieve it in order to send it to an xlsx to sql lite conversion function I've written.

Thanks :D

Here is my FileSensor

```
`file_sensor_task = FileSensor(
     task_id='waiting_for_file',
     filepath='*.xlsx',
     fs_conn_id="depot",
     poke_interval=30,
     retries=999,
     retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=10), 
     timeout=60 * 5,
     mode="reschedule",
     soft_fail=False,
 )`
```